# Pandas formated Datetime Column - Filter results by a specific Day of Week

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I only want results where day equals Thursday. I'm able to filter the open sites and ff which is first come first server but not sure how to filter by a specific day from my formated date. Thank you

```
def main():
    result = []
    print('Checking for available  campsites....')

    for unit_id in list(range(5095, 5096)) + [5117] + [5056] + [5078] + [5111] + [5113] + [5115] + [5119]:
        resp = requests.get(
            f"https://calirdr.usedirect.com/rdr/rdr/fd/"
            f"availability/getbyunit/{unit_id}/startdate/{day_today}/nights/60/true?").json()
        result.extend(resp)

    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df.rename(columns={'UnitId': 'Site', 'StartTime': 'Date', 'IsFree': 'Open', 'IsWalkin': 'FF'}, inplace=True)
    filter_by = ['Site', 'Date', 'Open', 'FF']
    df = df.filter(items=filter_by)
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda d: datetime.fromisoformat(d).strftime("%m-%d-%y %A "))
    # I only want results where day equals Thursday
    df = df[df['Open']]
    df = df[~df['FF']]
    print(df)
```

PRINTED RESULT

```
    Site                 Date  Open     FF
    5095   09-23-21 Thursday   True  False
    5095    10-19-21 Tuesday   True  False
    5095  10-20-21 Wednesday   True  False
    5095   10-21-21 Thursday   True  False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or why not just:

```
df = df[df['Date'].dt.dayofweek == 3]
```

Comment: `dt.day` returns day of month, you need to use `dt.dayofweek`

Comment: @AlwaysRightNeverLeft Ah sorry about that, edited my answer

Comment: Can you provide anymore info on how to implement this code. Thank you

Comment: How do I format my date column so I can use this option? Thanks

Comment: @timothytech Add the above line to the last line of your function.

Comment: I got this to work thank you all for your help!!

Comment: Nice answer! My rationale to use `day_name() == 'Thursday'` is simply that it is more explicit and obvious at a glance, as opposed to having to remind myself that pandas weekday indexes start with Monday=0 and counting up correctly (counting is hard for me sometimes :))

Comment: Oh wow... Just after writing my last comment, I realized that Thursday is `dayofweek == 3`, not `4`. I'll edit your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.day_name()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html). If you keep the `Date` column as datetime64 instead of converting it to string:

```
# Example data based on your final DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Site': [5095, 5095, 5095, 5095],
                   'Date': ['2021-09-23', '2021-10-19', '2021-10-20', '2021-10-21'],
                   'Open': [True, True, True, True],
                     'FF': [False, False, False, False]})

print(df)

   Site       Date  Open     FF
0  5095 2021-09-23  True  False
1  5095 2021-10-19  True  False
2  5095 2021-10-20  True  False
3  5095 2021-10-21  True  False

df[df['Date'].dt.day_name() == 'Thursday']

   Site       Date  Open     FF
0  5095 2021-09-23  True  False
3  5095 2021-10-21  True  False
```

Comment: could not get this to work either but thanks

Comment: What error did you get?